# can not understand intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent

I was reading intent & intent filter. i got the below code:

**In activity:**

```
 Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));  
 startActivity(i);
```

**In Manifest:**

```
<activity android:name="com.example.intentdemo.CustomActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">            
  <intent-filter>               
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
   <action android:name="com.example.intentdemo.LAUNCH" /> 
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:scheme="http" />            
  </intent-filter>         
</activity>
```

My question is that- am i not supposed to declare **android.Intent.ACTION_VIEW** , instead of **android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW** inside the intent?

Comment: I was writing answer for your HTTP question, why you deleted it ?

Answer (score 1):

[`android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) refers to the name of the constant `ACTION_VIEW` in the class `android.content.Intent`. The value of this constant is "android.intent.action.VIEW". Hence the difference.

Comment: And we may add, that, for sure it was a bit confusing to have the first intent classes of the Android system named that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the source code of `Intent` class, `ACTION_VIEW` is a `String` constant whose value is `"android.intent.action.VIEW"`...

```
public static final String ACTION_VIEW = "android.intent.action.VIEW";
```

so both refers to the same value which is `"android.intent.action.VIEW"`...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused in `android.intent.action.VIEW` and `android.Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. They both are totally different.

The way which you are using is **IMPLICIT INTENT**

These intents do not name a target and the field for the component name is left blank. Implicit intents are often used to activate components in other applications.

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));  
 startActivity(i);
```

**ACTION**

`Intent` object and is a string naming the action to be performed — or, in the case of broadcast intents, the action that took place and is being reported. The action largely determines how the rest of the intent object is structured . The Intent class defines a number of action constants corresponding to different intents. Check out list of [Android Intent Standard Actions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_intent_standard_actions.htm)

The action in an Intent object can be set by the `setAction()` method and read by `getAction()`.

[Check More for Intent and Intent-Filter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_intents_filters.htm)